# NSButton turns gray when pushed

Tags: swift, cocoa, colors, nsbutton, appearance

I have a NSButton with an image. When pushed the whole cell turns gray. How to prevent this? 
There are several posts about this topic. But most of them are like 10 years old. The most recent one was here: [NSButton background transparent after getting focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867340/nsbutton-background-transparent-after-getting-focus)

According to this, I tried with this code:

```
class overviewImageButton: NSButton {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    convenience init(appearance: NSAppearance) {
        self.init(appearance: appearance)

        self.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearanceNameAqua)
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {

        self.image = NSImage(named: "buttonImage.png")

        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: windowChanged, object: nil, queue: nil) {
            notification in
            self.image = NSImage(named: "buttonImage_highlighted.png")
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn´t work. The buttoncelll still turns gray when pushed. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize an image button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728599/how-to-initialize-an-image-button)

Comment: No, it´s not a `Possible duplicate`. This question was solved. This is a new topic.

Comment: The answer is the same. Only draw in `draw`. Set the properties in `init`.

Comment: Don't set the image in `draw` and don't call super twice. What is the style and type of the button? Or do you create the button in code?

Comment: What is `optionsButton`?

Comment: sorry, didn´t see your second-last comment...

Comment: No, button is created in interface builder. Style of the button is `Square`, type  is `Momentary Push In`.

Comment: Setting the image in convenient init, no picture shows up at all.

Comment: Your convenience init isn't called and executed. Controls in a xib or storyboard are initialized with `init?(coder: NSCoder)`. You can set the image of the button in the xib/storyboard, just put "buttonImage.png" in the image field.

Comment: You are right, setting the image in storyboard, the problem with gray background by pushing the button disappears. But I need to set the image in code, because it has to change depending on a Notificationcenter instance. So I´m still looking for a solution how to silence the gray highlighting when setting the image in code. I´ve updateted the code again.

Comment: What do you mean by a Notificationcenter instance? Do you want to change the image when you observe (recieve) a notification?

Comment: Yes, thats true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of this was already said by both [Willeke](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44729788/4113940) and [I'L'I](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44730277/4113940), so credit goes to them.

What Willeke said:

**Never** do anything in `draw()` except drawing. This method can get called as often as the screen refreshes. So currently you are basically trying to add yourself as the observer of the notificationCenter *really* often.

Here is what you could do: 
Write a `setup()` method and call that from each initialiser. Any one of them is called once for a button instance.

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.setupButton()
}

override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
    super.init(frame: frameRect)
    self.setupButton()
}

private func setupButton() {
    self.image = NSImage(named: "buttonImage.png")

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .windowChanged, object: nil, queue: nil) {
        notification in
        self.image = NSImage(named: "buttonImage_highlighted.png")
    }
}
```

You do not need to add the `init(frame:)` initialiser here. For storyboards the `init(coder:)` one is sufficient. I added it anyways, because you might want to initialise the button programmatically. You use the `init(frame:)` method there usually. If you add convenience methods, make sure to call the `setup()` method there as well.

What I'L'I said:
**To the important stuff**:
What I did to suppress the grey background on mouseDown was to simply call `isHighlighted = false` before calling `super.draw(rect)`.

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    self.isHighlighted = false

    super.draw(dirtyRect)
}
```

**Bonus:**
I see you somewhere defined a `Notification.Name`. You can define all of them in a project global extension to `Notification.Name` like this:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let windowChanged = Notification.Name(rawValue: "WindowChangedNotification")
}
```

After that you can use them everywhere like system notification names.

Comment: Simply awesome. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`NSButton` state appearances generally are affected with [`highlightsBy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsbuttoncell/1528459-highlightsby) and [`showsStateBy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsbuttoncell/1533225-showsstateby). These methods change what happens within the `NSButtonCell`, which I think you're referring.

↳ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsbuttoncell

Comment: Show how you're using it, since "still not working" is only adequate for people with psychic ability.